# Magento: Order Grid Row - How Change Size?

Tags: php, magento, open-source, e-commerce, magento-1.7

How can I change the size and order of the rows in Magento admin?

I need more weight for the order status.

Comment: Click things with your mouse. The grid is filterable/sortable/expandable. Page by 200 instead of 20.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to develop a small custom module with an orders grid rewrite to change the default columns behaviour, then you can use the **Enhanced Admin Grids** extension ([latest version on github](https://github.com/mage-eag/mage-enhanced-admin-grids), [Magento Connect page](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/enhanced-admin-grids-editor.html))